# How to access values from a form powered by typeform in python

Tags: python, django, typeform

I'm trying to use Typeform in my Python/Django website, and I wanted to know if there is a way to access the data from the form and do something with it.

Comment: Could you please share some code snippet, so that we can try to help you.

Comment: You can retrieve responses to your form via API: https://developer.typeform.com/responses/